# RaycastAll returns something that I do not understand

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying to make a drag and drop area withing a movable object.
My setup looks something like this:

[image]

**WhiteA** is the parent of **RedB**, both of them have *BoxCollider2D* on them including the **GreenC** . Objects **GreenC** and **WhiteA** has *RigidBody2D* component on them , **GreenC** makes a ray cast from its Anchor point on Mouse Up, and list the items that the *RaycastAll* hits.

If i drag **GreenC** over **RedB** *RaycastAll* will return: **GreenC - GreenC - WhiteA** instead of: **GreenC - RedB**.

If i move the **RedB** inside **WhiteA** so it will overlap, still keeping the hierarchy then the result will be : **GreenC - GreenC - WhiteA - WhiteA** instead of: **GreenC - RedB -WhiteA**

I Do not understand why it wont recognize **RedB** , It too has a *BoxCollider2D* on it. It only works if **RedB**  has a *RigidBody2D* component to.

**EDIT**: Added Code for Bart's request

```
private Vector2 MousePos;

void OnMouseDrag () {
    
    MousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y ));
    transform.position = new Vector3 (MousePos.x, MousePos.y,  transform.position.z);
}

void OnMouseUp(){
    foreach (Transform obj in HoveringOver ()) {
        print (obj.name);
    }
}

public List<Transform> HoveringOver(){
    
    List<RaycastHit2D > ObjectsHit = (Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position,  transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.down), 0)).ToList();
    List<Transform> AllObjectsHit = new List<Transform>();
    
    foreach (RaycastHit2D target in ObjectsHit) {
        AllObjectsHit.Add(target.transform);
    }
    
    return AllObjectsHit;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code please.